# Discord Bot Transcript TicketSystem

Tags: python, discord

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\KokoG\PycharmProjects\Logger\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 427, in _scheduled_task
await item.callback(interaction)
File "C:\Users\KokoG\PycharmProjects\Logger\ivanowz boosting\main.py", line 129, in delete
ticket_creator = guild.get_member(int(interaction.channel.topic))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'

Code:
@discord.ui.button(label="Save Ticket", style = discord.ButtonStyle.red, custom_id="delete")
async def delete(self,interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
channel = bot.get_channel(1115299753975107748)
guild = bot.get_guild(1098309499611271279)
ticket_creator = guild.get_member(int(interaction.channel.topic))
fileName = f"{interaction.channel.name}.txt"
with open(fileName, "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
async for msg in interaction.channel.history(limit=None, oldest_first=True):
file.write(f" {datetime.time} - {msg.author.display_name}: {msg.clean_content}\n")
emb = discord.Embed(title='',description=f'Ticket saved by {interaction.user.display_name} !')
embed2 = discord.Embed(title=f"Ticket Closed By {interaction.user.display_name}", description=f"Ticket Name: {interaction.channel.name}\n Ticket from: <@{interaction.channel.topic}>\n Closed from: {interaction.user.name}\n Transcript: ", color=discord.colour.Color.blue())
file = discord.File(fileName)
await asyncio.sleep(1)
await ticket_creator.send(embed=embed2)
await ticket_creator.send(file=file)
await channel.send(embed=embed2)
await channel.send(file=file)

Discord Ticket System